# Can you run "Full Analysis" in Fritz with a different engine?

Tags: analysis, engines, stockfish, chessbase, fritz

I have added Stockfish to the Deep Fritz GUI, and I even marked all engines except for Stockfish as inactive. However, when I run the "Full Analysis" it's still using Fritz.

Is there a way to use a different engine?

Comment: Have you tried *Engine->Change main Engine...* ? All you have to do then is select StockFish and click OK. Then click on *New Game* icon and the change will be applied, you should see title change from Fritz to StockFish. All that is left is to setup a position and run analysis... Welcome to Chess SE!

Comment: Thanks! that did it :) I don't know why I didn't see the button in the first place :P

Comment: I will post this as an answer so other viewers can see the solution more clearly. Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to *Engine->Change main Engine...* All you have to do then is select *StockFish* and click *OK.* Then click on *New Game* icon and the change will be applied, you should see title change from *Fritz* to *StockFish.* All that is left is to setup a position and run analysis...